# Return count value as zero if WHERE is not mete

Tags: mysql, count

I have a simple table:

```
-town          -canquote
london         datetime
manchester     datetime
```

I run a query

```
$sql = "SELECT town, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table WHERE `canquote`  > DATE('".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now"))."') GROUP BY town;";
```

Now I get rows back, and in this example I can get anything from 0 to 2 rows max.  If in the table the datetime for both towns is less than today it will return 0 rows.

But I always want 2 rows returned (or how ever many different towns there are) AND if the WHERE clause is not met then the count value should be zero...

```
[town]         [count]
london         5
manchester     0
```

Currently i dont get any towns when the count is zero.

If the count is 0 the town should still be returned with a count value of 0

Comment: Note that `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now"));` does not give you the start of today, it gives you the current timestamp to current second.

Comment: thats what i want i check if that date has expired so needs to be exact

Answer (score 0):

One way to get your desired result would be to take advantage of MySQL treating a boolean as either 1 (true) or 0 (false) in a numeric context, and SUMming the result of the conditional test rather than applying it in the `WHERE` clause:

```
$sql = "SELECT town,
               SUM(`canquote` > CURDATE()) AS `count`
        FROM table
        GROUP BY town;";
```

Note you can replace your date computation with the `CURDATE()` function, which will give the same result. If you want to include the time in the computation, you should use `NOW()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    town,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN canquote >= NOW() THEN 1 END) AS count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    town;
```

Note: There is no apparent reason to be invoking PHP functions here to obtain the current date at midnight.  MySQL's `NOW()` already does this.

Comment: CURRENT_DATE  is the date, but im using datetime in the table and i need to be able to check if the canquote date is greater than NOW() as in the exact time when query is made

Comment: is there injection risk if date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now")). is used as there is no user derived variables there just built in PHP functions/constants

Comment: @user2899094 Then use the `NOW()` MySQL function.

Comment: @user2899094 if you want to compare a datetime value, you shouldn't use `DATE` in your query as that will strip the time portion.

Comment: no it doesnt, it depends on the format you set in the first argument

Comment: I can use NOW() but that uses UNIX time or UTC i think, and all datetimes in my tables are based on UK GMT timezone, thats the reason for the PHP method of parsing the time into the SQL query the way ive done it